# popToRootViewController not returning popped UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I found some strange behaviour with `popToRootViewController` method.
According to it's declaration it should return popped viewControllers, but it's not if you call it during the `pushViewController`

```
class HomeTabNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func popToRootViewController(animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]? {
        let viewControllers = super.popToRootViewController(animated: animated)
        if let vcs = viewControllers, vcs.count > 0 {
            print("POPPED SOMETHING")
        }
        return viewControllers
    }
}
```

This is working as expected, if animation did finish before I call this.
But if I call this method during the animation still happening, it will return nil but it still pops to root viewcontroller after a slight delay.

I prepared a quick demo of that problem:

https://github.com/grzegorzkrukowski/UINavigationControllerBug

Of course I have different use case in my real app, but problem is the same.
Am I missing something or it's just a bug ?

Comment: Are you saying you're calling it twice for the same navigation? The second time it wouldn't return any ViewControllers because it wouldn't be popping any.

Comment: No, I'm calling it during the pushViewController animation is still happening - it's called only once

Comment: ah sorry...missed that part. My guess is that part of the state management doesn't update until after the animation is finished, so nothing's actually being popped. You could try logging .viewControllers before/during/after the animation to see what that looks like.

Comment: If doesn't remove anything from viewControllers, but after a delay it somehow removes them :/ It would be ok, as long as I could know how to detect that it removed something... popViewController is not being called in that process

Comment: Could you override viewControllers and use didSet ?

Comment: I guess that's not gonna happen until you overwrite whole array right ? If you append, remove items, didSet won't work. I could use KVO of course... but it's like a bazooka for a fly...

Comment: If it's a proper Swift array didSet will be called anytime after it's initialized and the `value` changes. I'm not 100% how the bridging works with Objective-C on that, but I think it works as expected

Comment: for reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254 Remember that arrays are structs in swift, so changing part of it's value will trigger didSet

Comment: I added sample project that proves the problem

Comment: It's not gonna work as it is @objc class as parent class, so it doesnt' work (didSet is not called)

Comment: Not sure I would call this a bug. It appears that if the push animation hasn't finished, the pop cancels the push, without the pushed VC ever being added to the stack. If you turn off animation, it works as expected. My guess is that if the pushed VC was added to the stack prior to animation finishing, that could cause other problems.

Comment: Yeah well - if it's returning nil from there, I would expect it to actually do nothing then ... or at least properly remove it from viewcOntrollers array, while doing animation in background

Comment: How could it do animation in the background? The user is supposed to see the animation as it happens.